# clarification on splitting individual trees in extra trees?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees

So I am a beginner in machine learning and just started learning about random trees in [this article here](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/9357/1/geurts-mlj-advance.pdf). When it talks about tuning the hyperparameter *K*, I'm a bit confused as to how it works. It says:

> The parameter K denotes the number of random splits screened at each node to develop
>   Extra-Trees. It may be chosen in the interval [1, ... , n], where n is the number of attributes.

So *K* would be the number that determines how many attributes to consider for a random split. Then to split, a random attribute from that set will be chosen? But what I'm wondering is that:

If *K > 1*, in a given set of attributes *[1,2,3,4,...,n]*, is it always a contiguous subset of size *K*? Or is it *K* random attributes chosen from those *n* attributes? And once you choose a random attribute from that subset, it is replaced or left out?

It also says:

> For a given problem, the smaller K is, the stronger the randomization of the trees

I'm confused as to why this is.

Answer (score 1):

> So K would be the number that determines how many attributes to consider for a random split. Then to split, a random attribute from that set will be chosen?

No, a random split is made for each of the randomly selected features, and these $K$ potential splits are scored and the highest scoring one is made.

> If K > 1, in a given set of attributes [1,2,3,4,...,n], is it always a contiguous subset of size K? Or is it K random attributes chosen from those n attributes? And once you choose a random attribute from that subset, it is replaced or left out?

We choose $K$ random attributes, not necessarily (and probably not) contiguous.  I think the original algorithm selects without replacement, and the implementation in `sklearn` definitely does it without replacement.  I could imagine another implementation deciding to do it with replacement though: still the split point for that feature could be different between the two selections.  (One more caveat is when a selected feature is constant for the population in the current node: these should be left out, and probably it is implementation-specific whether to select a new feature or just have fewer than $K$ in the end.)

> It also says:
>
> For a given problem, the smaller K is, the stronger the randomization of the trees
>
> I'm confused as to why this is.

The smaller $K$ is, the fewer features you consider for a split, and so the more the algorithm depends on these random choices (and is less likely to latch on to noisy, spurious correlations).  Compare to a full decision tree model, in which *every* split point of *every* feature is considered.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I strongly recommend displaying ALL PARAMETERS such as criterion, max_depth, max_leaf_nodes... in order to learn tree algorithms. In my experience, you'll learn a ton such as overfitting.

[image]